# Request Body returns null in API automation testing in C# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, automation

Here is my code

```
        public static RestRequest CreateReportRequest()
        {            
            restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic T1NUAxNFVxeTIwag==");
            using (StreamReader file = 
File.OpenText(@"C:\Automation\APIAutomationSuite\APIAutomationSuite\TestData\CreateReport.json"))
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                JObject Body = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);                    
            }            
            restRequest.AddJsonBody(Body);
            var response = client.Execute(restRequest);
            return restRequest;
        }
```

When I debug the code I am seeing the json request body value in "JObject Body" but when press F10 and move to the next statement (restRequest.AddJsonBody(Body);) the Body value becomes null. That throws a bad request error.
Please help me with this.

Comment: declare "JObject Body", outside the using statement. it could be loosing scope

Answer (score 2):

Your `Body` variable is declared inside *inner* scope of `using` statement. Thus when you're trying to reference it outside of `using` - it is undeclared.

You can move the end of your method completely into `using` scope, which, I guess, will eliminate your issue. For example:

```
...
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
    JObject Body = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);     
    restRequest.AddJsonBody(Body);
    var response = client.Execute(restRequest);
    return restRequest;               
}
```

[Understanding scope](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/understanding-scope-and-visibility-in-c)